# I want to know why only b is returned when I do like return(a,b)

Tags: c++, return, tuples

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int addmult(int ii, int jj);

int main() {
    int i = 3, j = 4, k, l;
    k = addmult(i, j); // 12
    l = addmult(i, j); // 12
    cout << k << "\n" << l; // 12 12 
}

int addmult(int ii, int jj) {
    int kk, ll;
    kk = ii + jj; // 7
    ll = ii * jj; // 12
    int a = (kk, ll);
    cout << "a = " << a << endl; // 12
    return a;
};
```

Hello, I want to know why the output result is 12 when I return like that.
I returned (val1, val2) like that, but I can find only b is returned.

Comment: `(kk, ll)` is not a tuple in C++. It's an expression where first `kk` is evaluated then `ll`. Thereby `kk` is discarded and doesn't have side effects. FYI: [Comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). To construct tuples, please have a look for `std::pair` or `std::tuple`. However, a return type `int` of your function doesn't allow the returning of `tuple`s or `pair`s. To me, it seems you may have worked in Python before. Please, consider that C++ is a very different language.

Comment: In short: `c++` is a language that must be learnt first

Comment: @Scheff'sCat - In `(kk, ll)`  the comma operator only discards the result of evaluating `kk`.   It does not prevent side-effects.

Comment: @Peter What side-effect has a read access to `int kk;`? I agree concerning arbitrary expressions (IMHO, that's what the comma operator is actually good and useful for) but a plain `int` variable?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat  -  It is evaluating an `int` variable that doesn't have side effects.   The way you described it suggests that is a property of the comma operator, which is untrue.

Comment: @Peter OK, maybe you misunderstood or I've chosen bad wording (or both). Referring explicitly to OPs source code `(kk, ll)` and naming it `kk` I wasn't aware of this...

Comment: @Peter Btw. [g++ -std=c++17 -O3](https://godbolt.org/z/K5vrqG8eK) agrees with me. I couldn't find any trace of `kk` in the generated code... :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you have an expression `(kk, ll)` it does not create a tuple. Rather it evaluates both expressions and returns the value of `ll`. So the `addmult` function only ends up returning that value.

There is the [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) data type in the STL which would let you return two values.

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> addmult(int ii, int jj) {
    int kk, ll;
    kk = ii + jj; // 7
    ll = ii * jj; // 12
    std::pair<int, int> a {kk, ll};
    cout << "a = " << a.first << ", " << a.second << endl;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have multiple return values and readable code.
Then define your own return type as a struct. (For pairs I always end up having to look back what first and/or second mean.)

```
#include <iostream>

// declare a struct that can hold all your return values
// and give them readable names.
struct addmult_result_t
{
    int addition;
    int multiplication;
};

// do your calculation and return the result
addmult_result_t addmult(int ii, int jj) 
{
    return addmult_result_t{ii + jj, ii * jj};
}

int main()
{
    int i = 3, j = 4;
    auto result = addmult(i, j);

    std::cout << "addition = " << result.addition << "\n";
    std::cout << "multiplication = " << result.multiplication << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _For pairs I always end up having to look back what first and/or second mean._ Fair point! :-)